# Dialog is not working

Tags: javascript

In the following code why the dialog is not working?

I import all the jar which are required, any reason behind it or any jar is required?

```
var val = $('#date').val().trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces

// Moved inside click handler
if (!val) { // Check if falsy value
    alert("hi");
    $("#dialog").dialog();//this particular line is not going to work propery
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is this Java? It looks like Javascript to me.

Comment: JavaScript isn't Java, please update your tag

Comment: show us the part where HTML tag with id dialog is defined please.

Comment: Because maybe the object comes true, maybe its the reason why you dont see the alert box. And this is javascript not java. However show us your view to see where it is failing

Comment: <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Search"  style="width: 70px; height: 40px" id="btnSubmit" /> <input type="reset" value="Clear" style="width: 70px; height: 40px" /></td>

Comment: i just want an alert box be more attractive and userfriendly

Comment: Why is no one concerned that he said `"..I import all the jar which are required"`. Essentially he is saying he somehow managed to compile that `JavaScript` using a `Java` compiler and it actually generated a `.jar` file which he has now added along to HTML file... and now his Alert Box doesn't even work. Why not?? He just wants a nice looking Alert Box... @carlosgil @RedRoboHood. @Stultuske @Alp

Comment: @GhanshyamMule, which tutorial told you to use that code with Java and make a **.jar** file? Do you have a link?

Comment: @VC.One Very good argument. You are right. Should I vote to delete my answer then ?

Comment: @Alp. there is nothing wrong with your answer. The Asker just needs to confirm if he wants to do **Java** (for native apps in Windows or Android etc) or maybe **Javascript** (scripting language for use in html web pages etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

line would NOT work because you basically do NOT have a tag with id="dialog" in your HTML (if the snippet of HTML is where it was supposed to be).

Make sure you have something similar to below div in your HTML.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

You can find more about JqueryUI dialogs [here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: but i had added above tag in html

Comment: @GhanshyamMule I am sorry dude. I missed a very important detail in your post, that VC.One pointed out. The problem you are facing may not be jquery/HTML problem. Please read VC.One's question and give him an answer. I may even delete this answer.

Comment: @Alp, he may still need it. Involving Java may be just his little mistake and that he really needs your answer? We'll see.